# Is it possible to develop Windows Phone 8 app using just HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I was introduced to programming by the web (HTML, CSS, JS, and some PHP) and never tapped on the desktop development for Windows so when I tried to read through the Windows Phone 8 developer documentations, I was totally lost at sea.

I once read a line or two on Microsoft website that says you can build WP8 apps using just HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript but could never find it any more. So my question is if it's possible?

I tried to find something to get started but it seems to me it all requires C#, C/C++, etc.? I thought they said the web is native in WP8? So in this sense, I should be able to develop apps using just HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript? Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course. You can use  [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)  to get your job done!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Visual Studio 2012 provides a template to build HTML5 apps. This template is available with WP8 SDK.
Alternatively you can use Phonegap, Titanium, Sencha.

https://github.com/matthiasxc/WP8-HTML-Tutorials

Answer (score 2):

You can use Phonegap to do that. Phonegap is a wrapper built around html5 technologies.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into the same issue, and found this wonderful post:

http://ax2012aifintegration.blogspot.com/2013/11/mvvm-windows-phone-8-app-using.html

Here, they make a normal WP8 app in Visual Studio, and adapt it to be written in HTML, CSS and JavaScript, using Model-View-ViewModel pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the upcoming Visual Studio 2013 (which is available as a RC version right now) will have the templates installed, but for now, as others have pointed out, PhoneGap is the best option. I remember having created a JS project in VS 2012, but now that I have a new computer I can't find the templates anywhere.

Here is a nice tutorial from MSDN on how to create an HTML5/JS project in Visual Studio using PhoneGap:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2011/12/23/tutorial-how-to-create-html5-applications-on-windows-phone-thanks-to-phonegap.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to create windows apps using html 5 and javascript
U can also develop windows phone apps without having the knowledge of coding...
To know more about it, check out:
http://www.techstorms.in/2013/10/how-to-develop-windows-phone-apps-for-free.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.