# from where should i start windows phone application development

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am newly in to the windows 8 phone apps development.
Please help me by telling in what languages I should have sound knowledge.
                   Thank you.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://developer.windowsphone.com/en-us) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205844/is-it-possible-to-develop-windows-phone-8-app-using-just-html5-css3-and-javasc).

Comment: Please read how to ask question in SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to try these video tutorials. These are form basics to advanced.

1.[Windows phone 8 for absolute beginners](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners)

2.[Windows phone 8 Jump Start[for in depth understanding]](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-Jump-Start)

I recommend you to go through these books:

1.[Windows Phone 8 Development Internals](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145373342.do)

2.[Windows Phone Toolkit In Depth 3rd Edition](http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/windows-phone-toolkit-in-depth-3rd-edition)

C# language should do fine for you :)

P.S. Accept the answer if your query has been solved. Thanks.

Comment: Nah, those Channel9 Videos are by far not that good, I would recommend the whole MVA Course (they are free) http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/windows-phone-8-apps-development-jumpstart#?fbid=XPt4fr3cEKS

http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/windows-8-and-windows-phone-8-app-development#?fbid=XPt4fr3cEKS

Answer (score 1):

C#. VB.net would also work as well as c++ for games but i'd recommend c#

Comment: Thank you mr.Steiner,Should i have knowledge in ASP and ado.net also??

Comment: Depends if you want to make a web backend that provides data as well. If You want push notifications You either need a backend like azure mobile Services or You write thst Service yourself. Also ado.net is mit supported. Ado.net would be used for dataconnection to *SQL Databases which is not supported in Windows and Phone 8 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone supports C++, C# and Visual Basic.NET. You could also develop hybrid applications in JavaScript with HTML for UI instead of using XAML.

Game development is done with Direct3D which is supported only in C++, but by using third party components you could use it in C#. You could also use some complete game development frameworks such as Unity.

So you see, there is a variety of languages to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

"Thank you mr.Steiner,Should i have knowledge in ASP and ado.net also??"

No, the main you should aim - WPF, Silverlight.

From microsoft certification site, we can see that to become Windows Phone Professional developer you need certificates in C#, Silverlight and something... So that means Silverlight is closer =)

Comment: In Windows Phone we use XAML and a subset of WPF (similar to the WinRT subset) but not silverlight anymore